# Zoom Effect on Hover of Image CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to add a zoom effect on hover of an image, I will post my code below:

```
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="space">
       <a href="www.google.com" id="myImage" runat="server">
       <img src="Images/myIcon" style="border: none;" alt="my text goes here" /></a>
    </asp:TableCell>
```

CSS:

```
.space {
padding-bottom: .6em;
}

.image:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

This is currently not running the hover css I have attached... any ideas of why it isn't running the hover css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.image does not seem to be defined in your example:

```
.image:hover img {
```

try:

```
.space:hover img
```

Answer (score 0):

use scale property to zoom and transition for animation

```
.img:hover
{
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

and for complete tutorial click here http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/image-zoom-in-on-hover-using-css3.php